# Added field to WIT in TFS is not shown in existing work items

Tags: visual-studio, templates, tfs, customization, workitem

We are planning to use TFS 2012, but, our process is not 100% defined, so changes in the work items and their properties are expected. I started a test with the Bug work item type, and created one Bug item. Then I export the bug template, add one field called "support ticket id" and then imported the work item type back into TFS. New bug items that I create show this new field as expected, but the existing bug item does not show this field. Do I have to execute something special to update existing items as well? I did everything from within VS2012, not from the command line.

Thx,

Wim

Comment: Apparently, none of the three refresh buttons that were on the VS screen were doing any good. After restarting Visual Studio and establishing connection to TFS again, the field was available for the old bug items :-( Either I hit the wrong refresh button (is there a fourth) or the refresh does not really work that good.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to clear the client cache.  I would have expected the refresh button to have done this, but will confirm tomorrow.

Here is where you'll find the cache for versions of Team Explorer:

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\<version>\Cache`

Answer (score 0):

Actually refresh at the project level is all that I ever needed to do. Failing that for some reason disconnect from the server reconnect and then do the refesh at the project level